# I created a database diagram and but other user is not able to view the database diagram. What access permissions does the other user need?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-diagram

I created a database diagram in SQL database but the other person in my team is unable to view it, it might be because of different access permissions to that server.

- What permissions does the other user need to be able to view the database diagram?
- Is there any other way I can send the database diagram to that user( like copy the database diagram somewhere and share it?)
- Which other softwares help in creating database diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference database diagram documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186345(v=sql.110).aspx

It states basically:

> User who created it and db_owners can view them.

Comment: Thanks Kritner! Is there any other way to copy the diagram somewhere else and send it the other person?

Comment: Well you can right click the canvas of the diagram and "Copy to Clipboard" though it won't have the interactiveness that the diagram itself has (it'll just be an image) - but that's one way to do it.